# Facebook wordpress site sharing with the wrong image

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I'm with a problem with a wordpress site and facebook sharing. My site does not have any sharing button, the share I'm talking about is when any user paste the url at facebook, the image that appears is some random image and not the logo that I want to appear.

What I've tried so far:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com">
<meta property="og:title" content="example name">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="example name">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/logo_example.png">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="105">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="72">
<link rel="image_src" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/logo_example.png" />
```

This code is an example, the links to images doesn't work.

Comment: Have you looked at WordPress plugins that can add all of this open graph data to each page automatically for you? I've used https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-open-graph/ with much success before. Open Graph is also used by LinkedIn and a bunch of other sites. This plugin lets you specify an image and text per post/page or a site-wide default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

At this site: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ I could debug the facebook metatags and discovered that my image has to be at least 200x200 px. Because it wasn't, facebook got always other images to build the share. So, I had to change my image and removed the width and height meta tags too.